# How to post parameters to server when a parameter changes it's value with every request (Iphone)

Tags: ios, iphone, post, afnetworking

I want to post parameters to a webpage via afnetworking. Here is the code:

```
<label for="id">Anv&auml;ndarnamn</label>
<input id="username" name="username" class="login" tabindex="1" accesskey="a" type="text" value="" size="25"/>
<label for="pw">Lösenord</label>
<input id="password" name="password" class="login" tabindex="2" type="password" value="" size="25"/>
<!--p>  
    <div style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">Om du &auml;r student och inte kan logga in</div>D&aring; beh&ouml;ver du f&ouml;rnya ditt l&ouml;senord.<br/><a href="https://sp.it.gu.se/    gusPwdRecovery/">Klicka h&auml;r f&ouml;r att f&ouml;r att byta l&ouml;senord</a><br />
</p-->                        
<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="_c5A9EF067-BDF4-2301-A37D-1D9E3255257A_kBB8220EF-613E-FA01-9122-6449323644CB" />
<input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="submit" />
<input name="submit" accesskey="l" value="Logga in" tabindex="4" type="submit" class="button right"/>
```

Here is my code in xcode:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": @"myusername", @"password": @"mypassword", @"lt": @"_c7ED1073A-3E62-1A4D-EC55-01AC6D285908_k5F4190DC-2873-9D7A-E03F-AD63C12CC48A", @"_eventId": @"submit", @"submit": @"Logga in"};
```

The problem is that "ld" paramater changes it's value with every post request I make to the webpage. And so I don't know what value ld paramater will have at the next request I'll make. What should I do in this situation? Is there any solution to this problem?

thank you in advance!

Comment: are you using database and a server backend code to do this? then make your api return the new id as a json

Comment: i am sorry, i am pretty new to this, what you mean by database and a server backend code? Here is my complete code for post request:

Comment: AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": @"myusername", @"password": @"mypassword", @"lt": @"_c7C9937ED-712D-16C2-A248-D373B45661AF_k69F90E27-0DF0-897C-110A-2F9BBD37B966", @"_eventId": @"submit", @"submit": @"Logga in"};
[manager POST:@"website/login" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {    
    NSData *data = (NSData*)responseObject;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to parse the ID.  You should use [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if the page is complex.  If the page is guaranteed to be this simple, you could also use NSScanner:

```
- (NSString *) findID {
    NSString *htmlString = // your HTML
    NSScanner *theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:htmlString];

    while (![theScanner isAtEnd]) {
        NSString *src;
        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<label for=\"id\">" intoString:nil];
        BOOL success = [theScanner scanUpToString:@"</label>" intoString:src];
        if (success)
            return src;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Do you know how I could do this by libxml2 parser? And also, to get the page's current HTML i need to send a request Then to post the login and password to the page I need to send another request. My question is won't the "id"paramater change every time I send request to the page, and thus the paramater i post for the new request be incorrect?